# how to find the intersection between three intervals?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to find a intersection between three line numbers.

eg:

```
    line 1 = 1.1 - 9.9
    line 2 = 2.4 - 8.5
    line 3 = 6.4 - 9
```

answer would be `6.4- 8.5`.

The current way I do has lots of if else. Is there other way I could do this other then having numerous if else.

Comment: Find the maximum of the lowers, and the minimum of the uppers. Make sure the former is not larger than the latter. You can use a loop for your processing so you should have "lots" of `if-else`. Since you haven't shown your code, I suspect that may be your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: This is a very broad question, but if you can compute the intersection of two intervals, you can use the same function again to intersect that result with the third interval.  Post what you've tried so far, and what doesn't work, and we may be able to help with the specifics.

Comment: @lurker thank you so much .. I did what you said .. I used nested std::max  and std::min to find the max and min

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a recursive template:

```
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
auto intersection(const T& a, const T&b)
{
    return std::make_pair(std::max(a.first, b.first), std::min(a.second, b.second));
}

template<typename T, typename... Rest>
auto intersection(const T& a, const T&b, const Rest&... r)
{
    return intersection(intersection(a, b), r...);
}


int main()
{
    auto const line1 = std::make_pair(1.1, 9.9);
    auto const line2 = std::make_pair(2.4, 8.5);
    auto const line3 = std::make_pair(6.4, 9.);

    return intersection(line1, line2, line3) != std::make_pair(6.4, 8.5);
}
```

Note that in this simple implementation, a pair where `first` >= `second` means an empty interval.

---

An even simpler function is to use the forms of `min` and `max` that take `initializer_list` arguments:

```
#include <algorithm>

template <typename ...Ts>
auto intersection(const Ts&... ps)
{
    return std::make_pair(std::max({ps.first...}), std::min({ps.second...}));
}
```

Thanks to [Jarod42](/users/2684539) for suggesting this.

Comment: Or even `template <typename ...Ts> auto intersection(const Ts&... ps) { return std::make_pair(std::max({ps.first...}), std::min({ps.second...})); }`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged as C++, I'm going to presume a C++ answer is required.

The boost interval library deals with exactly this issue and others related to interval arithmetic.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/interval.htm

Comment: Answers need to include enough information to remain meaningful and useful when embedded links go dead.